# Как защитить изображение от сохранения копии экрана?

Tags: screenshots, защита, изображения

Какие есть подходы к защите изображения от сохранения его через копию экрана десктопа или смартфона?

Comment: Самый простой способ - не дать юзеру нажать на PrntScr

Comment: А более сложный, но широко применимый?

Comment: А то, что браузер загрузил-таки картинку, и она находится в его кэше (и юзер может её спокойно достать оттуда), вас не смущает?

Comment: А чем продиктованы такие требования к секретности?

Comment: Самый надёжный способ -- при выводе заливать картинку чёрным цветом. Или любым другим. Всё, что Вы отдаёте браузеру, можно сохранить и скопировать.

Comment: @VladD есть же и другие способы сформировать изображение на экране, сгенерить на лету например.

@Montreal попытка переплюнуть SnapChat в части эфемерности сообщений.

Comment: Но никто и ничто не сможет помешать пользователю приложить свой монитор к сканеру...

Answer (score 2):

Не выкладывать изображение в интернет.

Только для IE (другие браузеры, слава богу, такой функционал не поддерживают):

```
<!--
/**************************************************
* (c) ArtistScope (www.artistscope.com)
**************************************************/
```

---

```
function do_err() {
    return true;
}

onerror = do_err;

function no_cp() {
    clipboardData.clearData();
    setTimeout("no_cp()", 100);
}

no_cp();
```

---

```
//-->
```

**p.s.** очищается **все** содержимое буфера.

**[Работа с буфером в ActionScript3](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/Clipboard.html)** и **[ограничения](http://blog.andrewng.com/2008/10/21/flash-10-security-changes-setclipboard-requires-user-interaction/)**

Comment: Вопрос не как вообще защитить, а только от сохранения копии экрана.

OpenGL, черезстрочное мелькание, видео, инертность человеческого зрения.

Comment: Что ж, добавил рабочий вариант для IE.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/cc163713(en-us).aspx

Comment: Интересный ход!  Ещё Flash умеет работать с clipboard, но, кажется, только по действию пользователя - клику мышкой и т.п. Просто флешка на странице не сможет раз в X секунд обнулять клипборд.
А на Mac экран копируется или в буфер, или напрямую в файл.

Comment: Добавил информацию по ActionScript3. Еще раз подчеркну, с помощью браузера этого сделать, как вы хотите, нельзя. С помощью стороннего софта - можно.

Answer (score 2):

Безотказного способа не существует. Но есть ряд советов:

1. Просто блокируйте кнопку PrntScr.
2. Проверяйте юзера на предмет установленных программ с названием, содержащим "Screenshot". Если была найдена такая программа, то или не впускайте пользователя в свою программу или просто убивайте процесс этой программы, например, каждые 100 мс.
3. Есть смысл очищать буфер при поступлении в него нетекстовых данных, например, если там оказался графический файл с размерами экрана (100% скриншот), то просто повредите или зачерните его. Но, обычно это мало поможет, если п2 не соблюдён и программа-скриншотер сразу пишет в файл, минуя буфер обмена.

Answer (score 0):

Я обычно ворую фотки так:

F12 --> Вкладка "Resources" --> Frames --> Бла-бла-бла --> Images

Пока не встречал ни одного сайта, где нельзя было бы дернуть фото таким образом.

М.б. везде плохая защита?..

Есть идея о защите от копирования - показывать картинки в SWF-файлах. Вот это действительно красивый метод! Возможно, существует какой-нибудь плагин для этого. Поинтересуйтесь...
А по поводу защиты от принт-скринов - Вам ответили выше.

========================================================

ИМХО: от таких, как я, не сработает ни один метод. Будь то проверка на принт-скрин, или вышеуказанный способ с флеш-объектом. Готов спорить на что угодно, что я все-равно сворую нужную мне фотку)))

Comment: Что будем считать критерием успешной кражи? =)

Например, я вам буду показывать не картинку, а видео, где картинка показывается с телевизионными помехами. Т.е. ни один кадр не содержит картинку целиком - всегда лишь части ее видны нормально. Но из-за инернтости человеческого зрения, у вас сложится-таки впечателние от целой картинки. Бытовой пример - быстро идти вдоль забора. 

Сможете вытащить картинку без единой помехи?

Comment: @sergiks: можно вытащить, например, видео.